# Can Intel i7 1065G7 run Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, cpu, system-requirements

I am new on Linux based operation systems.It will be my first time so I need your help.
I just bought HP Pavilion 14-CE3005NT and it has great hardwares but the processor. The hardware list of this computer is:

Graphics Card:Nvidia GeForce MX250
RAM:16GB(DDR4)
512 GB SSD
Processor:Intel i7 1065G7 (1.3 GHz)

And when I read Ubuntu 20.04 system requirements,it says 2 GHz dual core processor required.And my processor speed is 1.3 GHz. Would it cause a problem to run latest version of Ubuntu perfectly?

Note:I will be computer science student from this year. I will just use my laptop for coding and I wanna start using Ubuntu to improve myself quickly.So,please let me know if I can run compilers and other software for game development etc. too. Thank you.

Comment: Advice: Install Ubuntu and find out for yourself. If it doesn't work, re-install Windows.

Comment: The maximum Turbo Frequency of the Intel Core i7-1065G7 quad core processor is  3.90 GHz, so it should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it'll work.

First, your CPU speed is not 1.3GHz. Well, it may be at that speed *right now*, but the CPU has [a max frequency of 3.9GHz](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/196597/intel-core-i7-1065g7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html). The max, not the minimum is what the rating cares about.

It's a fairly new, capable, Intel CPU, from their top line. It'll run any software meant for normal desktop computers without big problems.

So go ahead, install Ubuntu 20.04. Your system is plenty good enough to handle it.

If you want to verify before installing, [try a Live medium](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install). You can install it right from the live environment if you like what you see.